# Python LDAP - Move user to different OU

Tags: python, linux, active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

Background:
I have been using the python-ldap module on my Linux machine to manage user accounts on a remote Windows Server 2008. I have been able to search for, create, and modify users, with the exception of changing a user's 'ou'.

I have tried using 'modify_s' and 'modrdn_s' but since modrdn only allows you to change the first part of a dn, I haven't had luck modifying the 'ou' or moving a user to a new 'ou'.

Temporarily I am creating a new user and copying all the attributes that I am able to from the old user, then deleting the old user. But this doesn't allow me to retain the user creation date and other un-editable information.

I have thoroughly searched the internet and found a few solutions, but:
on other operating systems: [How do you move a user to a different OU using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678748/how-do-you-move-a-user-to-a-different-ou-using-python)
and other programming languages: [Active Directory LDAP move user to different OU - Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129004/active-directory-ldap-move-user-to-different-ou-ruby)
Is this possible in python-ldap on Linux or are there any work-arounds?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`rename_s`](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.rename_s) and specify the `newsuperior` parameter.

Quick sample code:

```
ldap.rename_s('cn=UserName,ou=OldContainer,dc=example,dc=com', 'cn=UserName', 'ou=NewContainer,dc=example,dc=com')
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  
Though what is the "newsuperior" parameter? Is it the third parameter?

Comment: Yes, though it is also a named parameter (check the linked docs)